# bilinear/ linearity proof for the inner product property

Tags: inner-products

One of the properties for inner product says:

$$\left \langle \lambda u,v \right \rangle = \lambda\left \langle u,v \right \rangle$$
for all scalar lambda.
$$\left \langle u_{1}+u_{2},v \right \rangle = \left \langle u_{1},v \right \rangle + \left \langle u_{2},v \right \rangle$$

but why? Is there a proof for it?
In particular, why isn't the scalar lambda multiplied to both u and v?

Comment: It is part of the definition of [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space). Definitions need no proof.

Comment: Usually the linearity in the first argument is taken as an axiom of being an inner product. You may try to work to see if there are other things that can be used as an axiom to derive this linearity.

Comment: @drhab I agree. No questioning of definition. But why is it defined in such a manner?

Comment: An inner product defined like this appears to be very useful in mathematics. That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second equation is part of the definition of being linear in the first argument. So there is no proof, an inner product is defined to be linear in the first argument.

See [Inner product space -> Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition)

But if you want to prove something there is still hope: If you get a function and your task is to prove that it is an inner product, then you really have to show that it is linear in the first argument.

Example: Show that $\langle x,y\rangle := x y$ defines an inner product on the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

That's the definition of an inner product. There is no proof for definitions. Asking why is the inner product linear in the first argument is lika asking why triangles have three sides.

The question "why do we take such a definition" is different. The answer to that is at least in some way subjective:

> Because it is useful to us.

Many vector spaces we encounter have a "natural" inner product associated with them. $\mathbb R^n$ has a natural inner product which is very useful, since, for example, $\langle x,x\rangle$ is actually the square of the length of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Well since I also first had trouble accepting this as a fact here is another way you could prove it by combining those ideas together with say two arbitrary vectors:

lets suppose we have $ v=\begin{pmatrix} v_1\\v_2 \end{pmatrix} $ and 
$ w=\begin{pmatrix} w_1\\w_2 \end{pmatrix} $

such that we know $<v,w>=v_1w_1+v_2w_2$ as the definition of the inner product where we now want to go from $<v,w>=<cu+dv,w>$ and can observe

$$ v=\begin{pmatrix} v_1\\v_2 \end{pmatrix}=v=\begin{pmatrix} cu_1+dv_1\\cu_2+dv_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Now finally when we evaluate the weighted inner product at $$<v,w>=v_1w_1+v_2w_2$$
$$<cu+dv,w>=(cu_1+dv_1)w_1+(cu_2+dv_2)w_2$$
$$=cu_1w_1+dv_1w_1+cu_2w_2+dv_2w_2$$

where we can now regroup the terms $c$ and $d$ such that we get :
$$=(cu_1w_1+cu_2w_2)+(dv_1w_1+dv_2w_2)$$
$$=c(u_1w_1+u_2w_2)+d(v_1w_1+v_2w_2)$$

finally by the definition of the inner product we can substitute these values in get the simplified value:

$$=c<u,w>+d<v,w>$$